# Воспроизведение Flash-ролика по событию

Tags: flash, javascript

Вот решил вставить флеш на сайт и тут такая проблема. Флеш ролик воспроизводится при загрузке страницы. Есть ли какая-нибудь яваскрипт команда, которая при данном событии воспроизводит ролик. Флеш объект находится в тегах "object" и имеет свой айди.

Comment: Я думаю, будет больше желающих ответить, если вы приведете пример кода, а еще лучше ссылку на данное чудо.

Comment: Погуглите про параметры вставки объекта, там должно быть что-то, связанное с автозапуском!

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется ввиду проигрыватель от youtube, у него есть соответствующее API:

```
function play() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.playVideo();
  }
}
```

Если у вас есть доступ к исходникам flash-плеера, любую функцию можно сделать доступной через swfObject:

Actionscript:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback( "methodName", this, method );
function method() {
   trace("called from javascript");
}
```

Javascript:

```
function callAS() {
   swf.methodName(); 
}
```

Во всех остальных случаях, смотрите документацию к соответствующему плееру.

А лучше всего - используйте не Flash, а [HTML5 Video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), например [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации от Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html), чтобы отключить автопроигрывание при загрузке есть ряд параметров, конкретно для  тэга object это

```
<param name="play" value="false">
```

Но реально это может и не сработать в зависимости от конкретного содержимого ролика, который должен проигрывать Flash и который управляется ActionScript.

Чтобы запустить ролик из JavaScript, потребуется выставить наружу из ActionScript ту функцию, которая начнет проигрывание. Вы можете использовать [SWFObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/) для этих целей.